# In android how to set navigation drawer header image and name programmatically in class file?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, androiddesignsupport, android-navigationview

In android studio 1.4.1, I have created new Navigation Drawer Project which is default.My issue is in this project there is nav_header_main.xml file which is for navigation header image and name. I want this image and name should be set programmatically in my main class activity. How to do this, I tried lot but the app crashes.

nav_header_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout        
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/headerView"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="Android Studio"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="android.studio@android.com" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout            

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActivity.Class

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout headerImageView= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.headerView);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"working",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 246):

```java
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View hView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView nav_user = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.nav_name);
nav_user.setText(user);
```

Comment: navigationView.getHeaderView(0); why we use 0 there?

Answer (score 52):

As mentioned in the bug [190226](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190226), Since version 23.1.0 getting header layout view with:
`navigationView.findViewById(R.id.navigation_header_text)` no longer works.

A workaround is to inflate the headerview programatically and find view by ID from the inflated header view.

For example:

```
View headerView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.navigation_header);
headerView.findViewById(R.id.navigation_header_text);
```

Ideally there should be a method `getHeaderView()` but it has already been proposed, let's see and wait for it to be released in the feature release of design support library.

Comment: Can you please say how to add text view and image view also

Comment: Dude, as mentioned in the answer you can inflate the header layout (with imageview, textview or whatever views you want in header layout) using `inflateHeaderView()` method and can find view from the same inflated layout using `findViewById()`

Comment: NavigationView navigationView = null;
        View headerView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);
        TextView tv=(TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText("checking");  This my code eventhough app crashes

Comment: its working with given example and remember remove line from `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`   `app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"` because you have already inflate programmatically

Comment: @milapTank comment helped as the header view was inflating twice until I removed suggested line by him from my XML.

Comment: In version 23.4.0 this bug is still present.

Answer (score 28):

don't add header in xml add using code by inflating layout

```
View hView =  navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);
ImageView imgvw = (ImageView)hView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
TextView tv = (TextView)hView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
imgvw .setImageResource();
tv.settext("new text");
```

Comment: Yes, this is easily getting the result, thank you bhai .

Comment: how can I implement this in kotlin ?

Answer (score 7):

In Kotlin

```
    val hView = nav_view.getHeaderView(0)
    val textViewName = hView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName) as TextView
    val textViewEmail = hView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail) as TextView
    val imgvw = hView.findViewById(R.id.imageView) as ImageView
    imgvw.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery)
```

Answer (score 6):

First you need to access the navigation drawer in your MainActivity(or the calling activity) like this:

```
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
```

Then you need to remove the header layout from the activity_main.xml because the layout will be inflated programatically in the MainActivity. Your activity_main.xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout            

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Then in your MainActivity, we inflate the nav_header_main layout and get access to its views, in this case the ImageView and TextView

```
//inflate header layout
View navView =  navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);
//reference to views
ImageView imgvw = (ImageView)navView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
TextView tv = (TextView)navView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
//set views
imgvw.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image);
tv.setText("new text");

navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

You can read more [here](http://android-help1.blogspot.com.ng/2016/03/how-to-set-navigation-drawer-header.html)

Answer (score 5):

Here is my code
below perfectly working
Do not add the header in NavigationView 
tag in activity_main.xml

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/active_drawer_color" />
```

add header programmatically with below code

```
View navHeaderView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);
    headerUserName = (TextView) navHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.nav_header_username);
    headerMobileNo = (TextView) navHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.nav_header_mobile);
    headerMobileNo.setText("+918861899697");
    headerUserName.setText("Anirudh R Huilgol");
```

Comment: didn't work for me, it shows empty nav_header. (without text, and image)

Comment: @maximus I will upload the code on GitHub and you can look for the mistake what you have made.

Answer (score 5):

```
val navigationView: NavigationView =  findViewById(R.id.nv)
val header: View = navigationView.getHeaderView(0)
val tv: TextView = header.findViewById(R.id.profilename)
tv.text = "Your_Text"
```

This will fix your problem <3

Answer (score 4):

```
  nav = ( NavigationView ) findViewById( R.id.navigation );

    if( nav != null ){
        LinearLayout mParent = ( LinearLayout ) nav.getHeaderView( 0 );

        if( mParent != null ){
            // Set your values to the image and text view by declaring and setting as you need to here.

            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("user_data", MODE_PRIVATE);
            String photoUrl = prefs.getString("photo_url", null);
            String user_name = prefs.getString("name", "User");

            if(photoUrl!=null) {
                Log.e("Photo Url: ", photoUrl);

                TextView userName = mParent.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
                userName.setText(user_name);

                ImageView user_imageView = mParent.findViewById(R.id.avatar);

                RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
                requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_user_24dp);
                requestOptions.error(R.drawable.ic_user_24dp);

                Glide.with(this).load(photoUrl)
                        .apply(requestOptions).thumbnail(0.5f).into(user_imageView);

            }

        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using bindings you can do

```
val headerView = binding.navView.getHeaderView(0)
val headerBinding = NavDrawerHeaderBinding.bind(headerView)
headerBinding.textView.text = "Your text here"
```

Comment: you're my Heroine .  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT : Works with design library upto 23.0.1 but doesn't work on 23.1.0**

In main layout xml you will have `NavigationView` defined, in that use `app:headerLayout` to set the header view.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_menu" />
```

And the `@layout/nav_drawer_header` will be the place holder of the image and texts.

**`nav_drawer_header.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="170dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_size"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#40000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/navHeaderTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/navHeaderSubTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And in your main class, you can take handle of `Imageview` and `TextView` as like normal other views.

```
TextView navHeaderTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.navHeaderTitle);
navHeaderTitle.setText("Application Name");

TextView navHeaderSubTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.navHeaderSubTitle);
navHeaderSubTitle.setText("Application Caption");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have implemented it and it's working without any issues. I'm using this way from quite a long time.

Comment: I use this in design library 22.2.1 and it's working fine. Never tried on 23.1.0

Comment: i tried but application crashes. log cat error shows near navHeaderTitle.setText("Appliclation Name")

Comment: Your'e using support library 23.1.0? If so kindly look into the link given by @PareshMayani in above comment.

Answer (score 2):

`NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.addHeaderView(yourview);`

Comment: Hi @Роман Бяков, welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for your contribution. Are you aware that the question is more than 4 months old :-) ? Not sure if the answer still is needed... However, on different answers, try to explain a little bit more. What is `yourview` in your suggestion, and where should the OP put your code? Should she/he *add* the lines or *replace* same lines with yours? Explanations like these will help to try your answer and to see the value of your contribution. Good luck.

Comment: For what it's worth, there is no definitive answer to this problem and it is still active: are you aware that since this arbitrary 4 month deadline has passed, there have been 3 new posts :-)? Not sure your comment is needed... However, on future comments, be sure to stick to helping improve contributions, instead of discouraging them altogether.

Comment: Lots of questions that are older than 4 months old still get answers. In fact, some questions that are MUCH older (some YEARS old) are still getting answers! And that's a good thing. Although the OP may have gotten his answer, there are people who have the same question and for whom the question remains unanswered with the existing pool of answers. Since StackOverflow discourages re-posts of the same question, new answers will help other people with the same question. Moreover, APIs change over time and old answers sometimes contain code that may be deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but i am sure that this might help someone down the road.

You can simply get the headerView element of the Navigation view by doing this:

```
 NavigationView mView = ( NavigationView ) findViewById( R.id.nav_view );

 if( mView != null ){
     LinearLayout mParent = ( LinearLayout ) mView.getHeaderView( 0 );

     if( mParent != null ){
        // Set your values to the image and text view by declaring and setting as you need to here. 
     }
 }
```

I hope that this helps someone.

Comment: How to get the TextView? would it be `mParent.findViewById()` or just `findViewById()`?

Comment: can use mView.findViewById( R.id.text_view );

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use Kotlinx features

```
val hView = nav_view.getHeaderView(0)
hView.textViewName.text = "lorem ipsum"
hView.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   FirebaseAuth firebaseauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); 

   NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);   //displays text of header of nav drawer.
    View headerview = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    TextView tt1 = (TextView) headerview.findViewById(R.id.textview_username);
    tt1.setText(firebaseauth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());//username of logged in user.  

   TextView tt = (TextView) headerview.findViewById(R.id.textView_emailid);
    tt.setText(firebaseauth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());    //email id of logged in user.

    final ImageView img1 = (ImageView) headerview.findViewById(R.id.imageView_userimage);
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(firebaseauth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl()).asBitmap().atMost().error(R.drawable.ic_selfie_point_icon)   //asbitmap after load always.
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                    img1.setImageBitmap(resource);
                }
            });
```

I have made this code by myself with some logic...Its 100% working.....pls do upvote my ans.

The textview and imageview are from @layout/nav_header_main.xml

Answer (score 1):

It's and old post, but it's new for me. So, it is straight forward!
In this part of the code:

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
```

}
, I bound an ImageView to the LinearLayout, which contains the ImageView from the example, listed below. Mind: it's the same code you get when you start a new project, and choose the template "Navigation Drawer Activity":

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />
```

I gave the LinearLayout and ID, inside nav_header_main.xml (in my case I chose 'navigation_header_container' , so it went this way:

```
LinearLayout lV = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.navigation_header_container);

    ivCloseDrawer = (ImageView) lV.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    ivCloseDrawer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });
```

Note: I have a private ImageView ivCloseDrawer declared at the top, before onCreate (MainActivity).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method you can use to get header view and set data accourdingly

```
val headerView: View? = navigationView.getHeaderView(0) // Index of the added headerView  

// Now you can access child views of the header view
val titleTextView: TextView? = headerView?.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who use **KOTLIN** :

```
val headerview = binding.navDrawer.getHeaderView(0)
val NavDrawheaderviewRef = NavdrawerHeaderLayoutBinding.bind(headerview)

NavDrawheaderviewRef.btnSearch.setOnClickListener
{
Toast.make(this , "Hii buddy",LENGTH_SHORT).show()    
    }
```

Here :

- navDrawer =  id of my Navigation Drawer
- NavdrawerHeaderLayoutBinding
  = a func which is used to get a ref of header layout.
- btnSearch =  a button present in the header layout