# How to programmatically change the Text and Image of the Navigation Header for android

Tags: android, android-studio

I have looked everywhere and there are only so many people that have asked this question and so far nothing is working. I am currently working on an app that is based on fragments and when someone enters their id, it downloads their name and picture. I want to be able to change their name in the nav header field. Currently this is the code I am using

```
View header = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main, null);
        navigationView.addHeaderView(header);
        test = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.username);
        test.setText("HELLO");
```

That I obtained from here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190786

I also tried this method here [In android how to set navigation drawer header image and name programmatically in class file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33560219/in-android-how-to-set-navigation-drawer-header-image-and-name-programmatically-i)

Both of these end up with this error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.horizonservers.horizon, PID: 4042
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.horizonservers.horizon/com.horizonservers.horizon.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.addHeaderView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void'
android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.addHeaderView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
at com.horizonservers.horizon.MainFragment.onCreateView(MainFragment.java:153)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:601)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Does anyone know how to change the Text and image of the nav header side bar?  https://gyazo.com/23534130df4aff888708415b368aa1fa

Comment: did u find ur answer....i m also looking for answer

Comment: As far as I have seen so far there is no way of doing this. I contacted the dev of another app who's side bar does exactly that but he said he built his from scratch.

Comment: any other way to doing this..

Comment: The way I did this was by having the user login the first time. It would take their name and whatever else I wanted in the sidebar then save it to a text file. It restarted on its own and took the strings from the text file. Sort of ugly but it works at least temporarily ...

Answer (score 2):

```
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        test = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.username);
        test.setText("HELLO");
```

Maybe this would help!!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone finds this in the future, I was able to find a library that does pretty much exactly what I needed it to do. You can find it [here](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error, it looks like navigationView is null. Check to make sure navigationView was properly initialized BEFORE you inflate the header. Depending on how/where you're using fragments, the fragment lifecycle could be initializing the navigationView after the header inflation which will throw a NullPointerException.

If not the above, navigation header inflation has become very sensitive to the android environment used with recent design changes to the google design library. Below was my all-inclusive solution, and maybe it will work for you.

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View header = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);
test = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.username);
test.setText("HELLO");
```

Comment: Sorry this didn't help. I had found this answer earlier and decided to try it but I still get the same error.