# Navigation Drawer get intents

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation-drawer

This is my activity Login Code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case  R.id.email_sign_in_button:

            EditText em = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
            EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
            String password=pass.getText().toString();
            String email=em.getText().toString();
            String storedPassword =helper.getSinlgeEntry(email,password);
            String storedName =helper.getName(email);
            if(password.equals(storedPassword))
            {
                Intent i1 = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                i1.putExtra("1", storedName);
                i1.putExtra("2",email);
                startActivity(i1);
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Congrats: Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else
            {
                Toast Tpass = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalide Mot de Passe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                Tpass.show();
            }

            break;
            case  R.id.creer:
            Intent i1 = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, InscriptioNActivity.class);
            startActivity(i1);
            break;
    }
}
```

The Intent in the Code will be send it to MaintActivity with two value email and name

[image]

I want To put there and this is nav header

[image]

Like this example

[image]
I Want where i will put 
in MainActivty

```
getIntent().getExtras().getInt("1");
```

If something Missing  in code i will add 
Thank You So Much ^^

Comment: This may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33560219/in-android-how-to-set-navigation-drawer-header-image-and-name-programmatically-i

Comment: Thank You WORKED :D

Comment: Glad to help. Cheers!